# Can you run a virtual machine created in VMware Workstation 1.0 in the latest version (9.0)?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

If you have a virtual machine which was created with the very first version of VMware Workstation back in 1999, is it still possible to run this machine in the latest release of VMware Workstation (which would be 9.0)?

I don't actually have an image from VMware 1.0 to test this, but if anyone has one that they can legally share with me (i.e. one running linux or something similar) I would be really interested to try this out!

Comment: Cant say without testing. It might try to convert it to a newer format, but there is no logical reason that it *shouldnt* work.